# How to convert an urlopen into a string in python

Tags: python, string, urllib, python-2.x

Most certainly my question is not asked properly . Anyway, I am looking for a way to convert some data I ve extracted from the web to a list or a string (string would be better tho).

At the moment, this is what I wrote :

```
import urllib as web

message = "http://hopey.netfonds.no/posdump.php?date=20150209&paper=AAPL.O&csv_format=txt"   
data = web.urlopen(message)
```

data has a very weird type I ve never seen before (yes yes still new to that python thing). So any help would be very helpful .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not that stoopid. Just wrote the thing too quickly. Obviousy Ive got the " in the string ....

Comment: I'm not sarcastic, reading a tutorial is a good thing that you can do. I'm still reading many tutorials, including basic ones. In your future posts, try to demonstrate minimal research efforts and we'll be glad to help you. Sorry if my post sounded sarcastic, I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the metod `.read()`

```
data = web.urlopen(message)
str_data = data.read()
```

This will return the html on the page.
You can use `dir(web.urlopen(message))` to see all the methods available for that object. You can use `dir()` to see the methods available for anything in python.

To sum up the answer, on that `object` you crated you can call the method `.read()` ( like `data.read()`) or you can use `.readline`( like `data.readline()`, this will read just a line from the file, you can use this method to read just a line when you need it).When you read from that object you will get a string back.

If you do `data.info()` you will get something like this  :

```
<httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7fceeb2ca638>
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) .